# neo4j cannot use spatial.withinDistance but afaik right libraries in plugins folder (mac os x)

Tags: neo4j, spatial, neo4j-spatial

I have restarted my server after dropping the following jars in the plugin folders (both of the app and the database)

```
neo4j-spatial-0.24-neo4j-3.1.1-server-plugin.jar

neo4j-spatial-0.24-neo4j-3.1.1.jar
```

I get the error, when trying to make a call with the withinDistance

```
There is no procedure with the name `spatial.withinDistance` registered for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed.
```

The version of Neo4j I have is 3.2.2, same version on windows which works just fine with the same jar in the plugin folder of the database.

(Though my other code I am running with Spark and neo4j does not work on windows just on mac, computers are a passing fad. smh)

call dbms.procedures() results:

```
╒═══════════════════════════════╤══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╤══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"name"                         │"signature"                                                                                                           │"description"                                                                             │
╞═══════════════════════════════╪══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╪══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│"db.awaitIndex"                │"db.awaitIndex(index :: STRING?, timeOutSeconds = 300 :: INTEGER?) :: VOID"                                           │"Wait for an index to come online (for example: CALL db.awaitIndex(\":Person(name)\"))."  │
├───────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"db.constraints"               │"db.constraints() :: (description :: STRING?)"                                                                        │"List all constraints in the database."                                                   │
├───────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"db.createLabel"               │"db.createLabel(newLabel :: STRING?) :: VOID"                                                                         │"Create a label"                                                                          │
├───────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"db.createProperty"            │"db.createProperty(newProperty :: STRING?) :: VOID"                                                                   │"Create a Property"                                                                       │
├───────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"db.createRelationshipType"    │"db.createRelationshipType(newRelationshipType :: STRING?) :: VOID"                                                   │"Create a RelationshipType"                                                               │
├───────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"db.indexes"                   │"db.indexes() :: (description :: STRING?, state :: STRING?, type :: STRING?)"                                         │"List all indexes in the database."                                                       │
├───────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"db.labels"                    │"db.labels() :: (label :: STRING?)"                                                                                   │"List all labels in the database."                                                        │
├───────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"db.propertyKeys"              │"db.propertyKeys() :: (propertyKey :: STRING?)"                                                                       │"List all property keys in the database."                                                 │
├───────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"db.relationshipTypes"         │"db.relationshipTypes() :: (relationshipType :: STRING?)"                                                             │"List all relationship types in the database."                                            │
├───────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"db.resampleIndex"             │"db.resampleIndex(index :: STRING?) :: VOID"                                                                          │"Schedule resampling of an index (for example: CALL db.resampleIndex(\":Person(name)\"))."│
├───────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"db.resampleOutdatedIndexes"   │"db.resampleOutdatedIndexes() :: VOID"                                                                                │"Schedule resampling of all outdated indexes."                                            │
├───────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"db.schema"                    │"db.schema() :: (nodes :: LIST? OF NODE?, relationships :: LIST? OF RELATIONSHIP?)"                                   │"Show the schema of the data."                                                            │
├───────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"dbms.changePassword"          │"dbms.changePassword(password :: STRING?) :: VOID"                                                                    │"Change the current user's password. Deprecated by dbms.security.changePassword."         │
├───────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"dbms.components"              │"dbms.components() :: (name :: STRING?, versions :: LIST? OF STRING?, edition :: STRING?)"                            │"List DBMS components and their versions."                                                │
├───────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"dbms.functions"               │"dbms.functions() :: (name :: STRING?, signature :: STRING?, description :: STRING?)"                                 │"List all user functions in the DBMS."                                                    │
├───────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"dbms.listConfig"              │"dbms.listConfig(searchString =  :: STRING?) :: (name :: STRING?, description :: STRING?, value :: STRING?)"          │"List the currently active config of Neo4j."                                              │
├───────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"dbms.procedures"              │"dbms.procedures() :: (name :: STRING?, signature :: STRING?, description :: STRING?)"                                │"List all procedures in the DBMS."                                                        │
├───────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"dbms.queryJmx"                │"dbms.queryJmx(query :: STRING?) :: (name :: STRING?, description :: STRING?, attributes :: MAP?)"                    │"Query JMX management data by domain and name. For instance, \"org.neo4j:*\""             │
├───────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"dbms.security.changePassword" │"dbms.security.changePassword(password :: STRING?) :: VOID"                                                           │"Change the current user's password."                                                     │
├───────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"dbms.security.createUser"     │"dbms.security.createUser(username :: STRING?, password :: STRING?, requirePasswordChange = true :: BOOLEAN?) :: VOID"│"Create a new user."                                                                      │
├───────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"dbms.security.deleteUser"     │"dbms.security.deleteUser(username :: STRING?) :: VOID"                                                               │"Delete the specified user."                                                              │
├───────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"dbms.security.listUsers"      │"dbms.security.listUsers() :: (username :: STRING?, flags :: LIST? OF STRING?)"                                       │"List all local users."                                                                   │
├───────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"dbms.security.showCurrentUser"│"dbms.security.showCurrentUser() :: (username :: STRING?, flags :: LIST? OF STRING?)"                                 │"Show the current user. Deprecated by dbms.showCurrentUser."                              │
├───────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"dbms.showCurrentUser"         │"dbms.showCurrentUser() :: (username :: STRING?, flags :: LIST? OF STRING?)"                                          │"Show the current user."                                                                  │
└───────────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the neo4j-spatial-0.24-neo4j-3.1.1-server-plugin.jar should be enough to put there, no need to put the other file.
After server restart, you can see the registered procedures with this call:

```
CALL dbms.procedures()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, this is making me pull my hair out.  I agree it works on windows so should work here.  Then again, stranger things have happened.  I posted the results of the CALL dbms.procedures()

Comment: I just drop the neo4j-spatial-0.24-neo4j-3.1.1-server-plugin.jar into my plugin folder of my neo4j 3.1.3 and works like a charm.
It is possible that your jar corrupted. I should check it with the md5 checksum.

Comment: I did get one error, but not recently in the log about some spatial logger being missing and not able to load.  I haven't seen that yet.  let me totally restart the neo4j community not just stop start the server

Comment: Thanks for the sanity check, found the version neo4j-spatial-0.24.1-neo4j-3.1.1-server-plugin.jar and it seems to work!